# If statemts, only if the subject is of a certian class

Tags: python, string, list

For an assignment have to turn words into the dog lantin version of them, thats not the problem though, they love to find the conditions for our code to fail, so i think they will attempt to trip us up by having different class types in the auto code. My problem is i want to apply my function to a sentence, I can do it for an indivdual word, but I dont know how to have it apply for every word in the sentece. So i have one function here

```
def dog_latinify_word(word):
    """Takes a word and returns the dog latin version of the word"""
    first_letter = word[0]
    first_letter.lower()
    vowels = ('a','e','i','o','u','1','2','3','4','5',
          '6','7','8','9','0')
    dogify_vowel = word + 'woof'
    dogify_constant = word[1:] + word[0] + "oof"
    if word.startswith(vowels):
        result = dogify_vowel
    elif first_letter != vowels:
        result = dogify_constant
        return result
```

but i dont know how to have this function work on every item in a list, because i need to have each word be "dog latinified"

So I have another function to take the sentence that then splits it so each word is its own item in a list, but when I go to call on this function, it only works for class str, and not list. So in my rambling ways can someone point me in the direction of having this function apply into every item in a list, rather than just a string

my code for the secondary function

```
def dog_latinify_sentence(sentence):
    """translate a sentence into dog latin"""
    str_split = sentence.split(' ')
    dogify_sentence = dog_latinify_word(str_split)
    return dogify_sentence
```

sorry for the rambling im very tired

Comment: Can you add code of `another function to take the sentence that then splits it so each word`

Comment: `return` statement should be indented with only one tab. Otherwise the function did only return in the `elif` statement

Comment: Olaf Nankman, ye i have that it my original code, just tired and auto went and added to many when pasting it into the text box without realising

Comment: I think split returns an array, so you should iterate through the array of words, translate each word and then combine the words to a sentence. In your function, you tried to dogify the array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by just adding a for loop over the list object like this.

```
def dog_latinify_sentence(sentence):
    """translate a sentence into dog latin"""
    str_split = sentence.split(' ')
    dogify_sentence = ""
    for s in str_split:
            dogify_sentence += dog_latinify_word(s)    
    return dogify_sentence
```

Above code removes spaces between words. In case you want to preserve spaces,

```
dogify_sentence = " ".join([dog_latinify_word(s) for s in str_split])
```

It just gets results from `dog_latinify_word()` and stitch them back!

Comment: Oh man I feel dumb, didnt even process the idea of a for loop, ty for help guys